Smooth periodic extension of a function on $[0,1)^d$ to $\mathbb R^d$
Here is my goal: Given $n\in\mathbb N_0\uplus\{\infty\}$, I want to construct a function $q:[0,1)^d\to(0,\infty)$ such that $q\circ\iota\in C^n(\mathbb R^d)$, where $$\iota:\mathbb R^d\to[0,1)^d\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor.$$ I actually would like to know a canonical way to construct $q$ from a given function $p\in C^n((0,1)^d)$ with $p>0$; i.e. I want that $q$ and $p$ coincide on $(0,1)^d$. If that's not possible, maybe we can achieve that $q$ and $p$ at least coincide on $(\varepsilon,1-\varepsilon)^d$ for a user-defind $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$. Is this possible?

I first started without the given $p$ and considered $q(x):=e^{-\|x-.5\|^2}$ for $x\in[0,1)^2$, where $.5$ is substracted componentwisely. However, with this $q\circ\iota$ is not even continuous at $x=k$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z^d$. Here is a plot for $d=1$:

When I change this in a crude way to $$\tilde q(x):=\sum_{k\in\{-1,0,1\}^d}q(x-k)\prod_{i=1}^d\chi(x_i-k_i),$$ where $\chi(t):=e^{-\alpha t^2}$ for $t\in\mathbb R$, then it seems to work. Here is a plot for $\alpha=10$ and $d=1$: 
However, I'm uncertain whether this really needs to be that complicated. I would like it to be more systematic. And, clearly, these approaches did not try to coincide with a given function $p$.
